# How should I delete a wrong commit and move origin

Tags: ios, xcode, git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a big mess in source tree. I work in XCode. A teammate and I worked for a couple of days in parallel and when we tried to merge both branches, Source Tree corrupted the files. I continued to work (in the blue line) but the origin still points to the corrupted commit. I've already re done the work in the yellow branch. 
How Can I delete all the yellow and red and point to the actual master?

[image: Source Tree Mess]

Answer (score 1):

```
git push -f origin master
```

**Warning:** Usually, push refuses to update a remote ref that is not an ancestor of the local ref used to overwrite it.
This flag disables these checks, and can cause the remote repository to lose commits; use it with care.